# Ubuntu core on a ChromeBox

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core

Has anyone gotten Ubuntu core working on a Chromebox? I followed the instructions for the Intel NUC and it seems to write the img to the harddrive, but on reboot I get the same problem that it will not run the image from the disk. Previously I removed the stock firmware and have the firmware from MrChromeBox running in legacy mode.

In a seperate test I was able to get Ubuntu core to run from the USB drive but I really want to have it on the hard drive.

I can also run full Ubuntu from the USB and that is how I wrote the Ubuntu core to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if anyone is trying the same thing but I could not get it working with SeaBIOS: The Legacy Boot. I ended up using UEFI and it worked. Just follow the instructions for Intel NUC as it is a similar install.